# Python glob returns empty for folder mounted from Network File System?

Tags: linux, networking, filesystems, glob, nfs

I don't know what is the name of this problem from Network File System (NFS) as it makes Python glob returns empty (and glob can return file path only after what I do below).

```
import glob 
glob.glob("/eodata/Landsat-8/OLI_TIRS/L1TP/2018/09/29/LC08_L1TP_205031_20180929_20180929_01_RT_MTI//*_B9.TIF")
[] # Return empty until the parent folders is reached manually below
```

If I use this command on this mounted point for NFS

```
ls -l /eodata/Landsat-8/OLI_TIRS/L1TP/2018/09/29/
```

It returns:

```
ls: cannot access '/eodata/Landsat-8/OLI_TIRS/L1TP/2018/09/29/': No such file or directory
```

Then, I will have to go deeper to subfolders:

```
ls -l /eodata/Landsat-8/OLI_TIRS/L1TP/2018/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Jul 23 17:47 01
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Jul 23 17:47 02
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Jul 23 17:47 03
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 May 15  2018 04
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Sep  2 10:10 09
```

Then, another level for subsub folder

```
ls -l /eodata/Landsat-8/OLI_TIRS/L1TP/2018/09
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Sep  2 10:10 01
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Sep  2 13:01 02
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Sep  3 12:01 03
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Sep  4 12:32 04
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Sep  5 11:38 05
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody 4294967294 0 Sep  2 10:10 29
```

The subsub folder **29** (date) exists in Network File System but somehow it needs to be fetched manually from folder **2018** (year) then folder **09** (month) before it works:

```
import glob
glob.glob("/eodata/Landsat-8/OLI_TIRS/L1TP/2018/09/29/LC08_L1TP_205031_20180929_20180929_01_RT_MTI")
# Now it found the folder after the ancestor folders are listed by ls
['/eodata/Landsat-8/OLI_TIRS/L1TP/2018/09/29/LC08_L1TP_205031_20180929_20180929_01_RT_MTI']
```

I think the problem can be due to the failure of NFS for this path (2018/09) which makes it work unreliably.